# Check checkboxlist Items as value in querystring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to mark checkboxlist item selected if it's value found in QueryString. e.g.

> www.abcd.com/pproducts.aspx?price=1001-2000|2001-5000|5001-10000.

In this url I am filtering products with 3 different price range. Now I have checkboxlist which contains this prices like below

> 1001-2000
>
> 2001-5000
>
> 5001-10000
>
> above-10000

so now I want to it should get selected 1001-2000, 2001-5000, 5001-10000

From below code I am redirecting page & making url

```
private void priceRange_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedPriceRange = priceRange.SelectedValue.ToString;
    foreach (ListItem chk in priceRange.Items) {
        if (selectedPriceRange.Contains(chk.Value)) {
            chk.Selected = true;
        }
    }

    Response.Redirect((Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) + "?price=" + selectedPriceRange);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are having?

Comment: @John I don't understand how to check items which are present in querystring value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string price = Request.QueryString["price"];                           
string[] priceList = price.Split('|');                                  
foreach (string p in priceList)                                               
{                                                                            
    if (chkList.Items.FindByText(p) != null)                                  
    {                                      
          chkList.Items.FindByText(p).Selected = true;                        
    }                                                                           
}
```

Above code will select each checkbox as per the value passed in query sting.

Comment: Hence this is right solution but there are some drawback of this. Can you please solve my this issue. As per querystring checkbox item gets selected perfectly but suppose If I uncheck particular item from it then it doesn't get uncheck becuase pageLoad event executed first & while loading it gets that querystring again from url & item get selected again. How to escape from this? Seethis link i have posted question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416897/uncheck-item-from-checkboxlist-which-gets-selected-with-querystring-onload