# Uncheck item from checkboxList which gets selected with querystring onLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have checkboxList which has autopostback true. I have made it in such way in which, on SelectedIndexChanged it gets redirected to same page with querystrting. Querystring value gets generated with selected items. Something like this
www.abcd.com/product?price=2000|3000|5000

So when page gets load the Checkboxlist items gets selected where its value is 2000,3000,5000 etc. But here I have drawback is that when I uncheck any item then agin first it executes pageLoad event code & there it finds value which is uncheck & gets selected again. In short unchecked items gets selected again.

PageLoadevent(Checkbox Items gets selected with querystring values)

```
string PageUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
if (PageUrl.Contains("price")) {
    string price = Request.QueryString("price");
    string[] priceList = price.Split('|');
    foreach (string p in priceList) {
        if (priceRange.Items.FindByValue(p + "|") != null) {
            priceRange.Items.FindByValue(p + "|").Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

SelectedIndexChanged(URL created with querystring & redirected)

```
string pageURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string strPrice = Request.QueryString("price").ToString;
if (totalcount > 1) {
    foreach (ListItem chk in brandsList.Items) {
        if (chk.Selected == true) {
            selectedBrands += (chk.Value);
        }
    }
    selectedBrands = selectedBrands.Remove(selectedBrands.Length - 1);

    Response.Redirect((Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?") + "&brand=" + selectedBrands + "&price=" + strPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string price = Request.QueryString["price"];
    string[] priceList = price.Split('|');

    foreach (string p in priceList)
    {
        if (chkList.Items.FindByText(p) != null)
        {
            chkList.Items.FindByText(p).Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Enclose logic of checkbox selection into IsPostBack condition in page load event. As above. When your page get postback your selection remain as it.